# Dygraphs.js not showing second value

Tags: javascript, json, csv, charts, dygraphs

I have this website, where i use [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) to create graph for currency compare, everything works fine except this strange behavior

[image: Date,EUR,CHF,CAD]

Grph only show first and third value, always skip second .

```
 g2 = new Dygraph(
                   document.getElementById("graphdiv2"), csv,
                   {
                       showRangeSelector: true,
                       title: Value1SFontcolor + Value2SFontcolor + Value3SFontcolor,
                       fillGraph: true,
                       animatedZooms: true,
                       colors: ['blue', 'green', 'purple'],
                       underlayCallback: function (ctx, area, dygraph) {
                           ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                           ctx.strokeRect(area.x, area.y, area.w, area.h);
                           area.color = 'black';
                       }
                   });
```

csv :
Date,EUR,CNY,CHF 
2012/12/10,113.942200,0.000000,94.307400 
etc...

How to resolve this bug, i copy js files from offical site

Comment: is it part of your real csv file ? Because there is no CAD.. Could you give me the real csv to test with real datas ? And could you give me your CSS for class `.dygraph-legend` please ? Here is a working test that show the 3 values : https://jsfiddle.net/uw6Lt4vp/

Comment: Thanks @aprovent for remade me of Css class for Dygraphs, my problem was pretty stupid i have remove display none and everything works fine now <br>   
.dygraph-legend span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

Comment: You're welcome. We always search for big problems first and sometimes it's the little ones ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in css file, i change this 
  `.dygraph-legend span:nth-child(2) { display: none; }` 
 and everything works fine... douh